# How to add information to a checkbox in django-admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In my Django admin (change_form) I have several checkboxes.(not only delete) some of them in TabularInline.
I want to let the users know what is going to be happened when they select a checkbox. See picture below.
I have searched alot but couldn’t find anything? I don't know where to search!! Form!

[image]

Comment: It depends where that checkbox is. If it's part of the main form of your model, just override the `form` of your `ModelAdmin`. But it looks like this is the **deletion field** of a formset (is this a `TabularInline`?) in which case, you should [override the `formset` of the `TabularInline`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.formset). After calling `super().__init__()` in your `formset`, you can try overriding the `self.fields[DELETION_FIELD_NAME]` field's widget. Not super easy, look at the source code of `django.forms.formsets`.

Comment: This is a TabularInline. Do I need to call super().__init__() in django-admin. somehwere like: class PeeringSessionInlineAdmin(NestedTabularInline):
    fields = ('connection',) --------------assuming the connection is the checkbox. Anyway your answer will help me where to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `tabular.html` template

this part respond for chek box display

**Original**

```
{% if inline_admin_formset.formset.can_delete %}
  <td class="delete">{% if inline_admin_form.original %}{{ inline_admin_form.deletion_field.field }}{% endif %}</td>
{% endif %}
```

**Modified**

```
{% if inline_admin_formset.formset.can_delete %}
  <td class="delete">{% if inline_admin_form.original %}{{ inline_admin_form.deletion_field.field }}test{% endif %}</td>
{% endif %}
```

**Result**

[image]

After you create modified version of `tabular.html` set it as template in Inline class you want to change.

```
class YourInline(admin.TabularInline):
    template = 'your_path_to_modified_tabular_html/tabular.html'
```